# Building MQMD header in compute node of IBM message broker

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I'm having trouble trying to add MQMD header in compute node. 
Tried something like that:

```
SET OutputRoot.Properties = InputRoot.Properties;
CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot DOMAIN('MQMD') NAME 'MQMD';
SET OutputRoot.MQMD.Format =  MQFMT_NONE; 
SET OutputRoot.MQMD.CodedCharSetId = 1208;
SET OutputRoot.MQMD.Encoding = 546;
```

But it always ends up with this exception:

```
Text:CHARACTER:Caught exception and rethrowing
Insert
Type:INTEGER:14
Text:CHARACTER:test.MyAdp.AddHeader
RecoverableException
File:CHARACTER:F:\build\slot1\S900_P\src\CommonServices\ImbValue.cpp
Line:INTEGER:989
Function:CHARACTER:ImbValue::stateError
Type:CHARACTER:
Name:CHARACTER:
Label:CHARACTER:
Catalog:CHARACTER:BIPmsgs
Severity:INTEGER:3
Number:INTEGER:2329
Text:CHARACTER:Value not valid
```

For sure, without adding MQMD header everything works perfectly well. 
I tried to use other formats as MQFMT_STRING, MQFMT_RF_HEADER_2 (with MQRFH2 header added next) but with the same result.

Can anyone give me any clue?
Is it possible to get some more meaningful diagnostics from broker somehow?

**UPD**
Here is trace out before entering Compute node which tries to add MQMD header. The trace node after Compute is never reached.

```
( ['GENERICROOT' : 0xac05710]
(0x01000000:Name):Properties = ( ['GENERICPROPERTYPARSER' : 0xaf5ccc0]
(0x03000000:NameValue):MessageSet             = '' (CHARACTER)
(0x03000000:NameValue):MessageType            = '' (CHARACTER)
(0x03000000:NameValue):MessageFormat          = '' (CHARACTER)
(0x03000000:NameValue):Encoding               = 546 (INTEGER)
(0x03000000:NameValue):CodedCharSetId         = 0 (INTEGER)
(0x03000000:NameValue):Transactional          = TRUE (BOOLEAN)
(0x03000000:NameValue):Persistence            = FALSE (BOOLEAN)
(0x03000000:NameValue):CreationTime           = NULL
(0x03000000:NameValue):ExpirationTime         = -1 (INTEGER)
(0x03000000:NameValue):Priority               = 0 (INTEGER)
(0x03000000:NameValue):ReplyIdentifier        = X'000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' (BLOB)
(0x03000000:NameValue):ReplyProtocol          = 'UNKNOWN' (CHARACTER)
(0x03000000:NameValue):Topic                  = NULL
(0x03000000:NameValue):ContentType            = '' (CHARACTER)
(0x03000000:NameValue):IdentitySourceType     = '' (CHARACTER)
(0x03000000:NameValue):IdentitySourceToken    = '' (CHARACTER)
(0x03000000:NameValue):IdentitySourcePassword = '' (CHARACTER)
(0x03000000:NameValue):IdentitySourceIssuedBy = '' (CHARACTER)
(0x03000000:NameValue):IdentityMappedType     = '' (CHARACTER)
(0x03000000:NameValue):IdentityMappedToken    = '' (CHARACTER)
(0x03000000:NameValue):IdentityMappedPassword = '' (CHARACTER)
(0x03000000:NameValue):IdentityMappedIssuedBy = '' (CHARACTER)
)
(0x01000000:Name):BLOB       = ( ['none' : 0xb30d460]
(0x03000000:NameValue):BLOB = X'314........d0a' (BLOB)
)
)
```

**UPD2** Here is fragment of user trace, message appears in try-catch node right after returning from compute node that creates MQMD.

```
2015-09-14 13:20:06.936871     1200   UserTrace   BIP2539I: Node '': Evaluating expression ''InputRoot.BLOB.BLOB || CAST(header AS BLOB CCSID 1208)'' at ('test.MyAdp_AddHeader.Main', '31.51'). This resolved to ''X'314....3d0d'''. 
2015-09-14 13:20:06.937023     1200   UserTrace   BIP2566I: Node 'test.MyAdp.AddHeader': Assigning value       ''X'314...6d0'... (data of len 3915 truncated)'' to field / variable ''OutputRoot.BLOB.BLOB''. 
2015-09-14 13:20:06.937043     1200   UserTrace   BIP2537I: Node 'test.MyAdp.AddHeader': Executing statement   ''RETURN TRUE;'' at ('test.MyAdp_AddHeader.Main', '33.4'). 
2015-09-14 13:20:06.937718     1200   UserTrace   BIP4081I: Message propagated to catch terminal from try-catch node 'test.MyAdp.ErrorHandler.Timer.Try Catch'. 
                                   The try-catch node 'test.MyAdp.ErrorHandler.Timer.Try Catch' has caught an exception which occurred in a node connected to its try terminal. The message has been augmented with an exception list and is propagating it to any nodes connected to its catch terminal for further processing. See the following messages for details of the exception list. 
                                   No user action required.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough detail given to tell what is happening.  What version of MB/IIB are you using?

You might be hitting the problem described [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC70416).

With that in mind, try changing your ESQL to:

```
SET OutputRoot.Properties.CodedCharSetId = 1208 ;
SET OutputRoot.Properties.Encoding = 546 ;
SET OutputRoot.MQMD.Format = MQMFT_NONE ;
SET OutputRoot.MQMD.CodedCharSetId = 1208 ;
SET OutputRoot.MQMD.Encoding = 546 ;
...
```

Comment: Capture more detailed diagnostics by recreating the problem with user trace enabled.  Start [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/an01310_.htm) for information about user trace.  A summary of the user trace procedure is [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21177321#1).

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but setting properties as above changed nothing in my case. BTW, the link to problem description is broken.

Comment: Forgot about the version, I use IIB 9.0

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the broken link, which I have updated.  I think we need a user trace to get more diagnostics.

Comment: Just added trace out, please let me know if you have any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Some attributes in your Properties folder could be unexpectedly null.
The issue occurs when they are copied to the MQMD folder.
A user or sys trace will show you which one.

Is your issue related to the Timeout Notification node?
I had the issue with Properties.CreationTime = null
I saw others having the issue with Properties.Topic = null

I coded it to bypass the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, the issue really could be related to Timout notification node, as the flow starts with it. However I see that Properties.CreationTime is filled, only Properties.Topic is null. Any suggestion about what it could be filled with?

Comment: Topic can stay null if you are not using it.
A trace will show you what's missing.

Comment: Just added trace out, please let me know if you have any suggestion.

Comment: Let a time controlled message (not a queue input) go thru and stop your trace.
Then analyse your trace.

Comment: Not sure I got the point. The posted trace was produced by a time controlled message. What else can we get from tracing?

Comment: Hmm, you used a trace node.
See the upper comment  
    A summary of the user trace procedure is [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21177321#1).
     –  @Steve Parsons Aug 24 at 19:29

Answer (score 1):

Did you try changing 

`CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot DOMAIN('MQMD') NAME 'MQMD';`

with

`CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot DOMAIN('MQMD');`

There is no need to specify name

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the format as a character value? According to the documentation this is what is expected:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ad09700_.htm

ie/

```
SET OutputRoot.MQMD.Format =  'MQFMT_NONE';
```

Comment: That sounds a bit strange for me, as normally MQFMT_NONE is resolved to a string containing several spaces. Anyway, tried setting this with no success.

Comment: The MQMD parser will turn it into a the value represented by the MQ symbolic constant when it serialises the MQMD. the exception you posted is being thrown because the ESQL engine is expecting one datatype and you are giving it a different one. With that in mind when you use the sample I posted above do you get exactly the same exception or do you know get something else going wrong?

Comment: Yes, the exception was exactly the same.